# Scientific sources/ literature regarding (spanish) speech rate

Tags: resource-request, spanish, syllables, prosody

I'm interested in scientific sources or literature regarding **speech rate/ tempo of speech** of the Spanish language. Do you know any?

Specifically, I'm looking for sources that compare the speech rate of speakers from different spanish-speaking countries. I could only find [Schwab (2015)](https://revistas.ucr.ac.cr/index.php/filyling/article/view/21193/21355) who lists different linguisitc variants and the according speech rates, other sources restrict their analysis to one variant.

Sources don't have to be in English.

Comment: Do they measure by syllable? Spanish is a syllable-timed language, and "speech rate" can mean a number of things, depending on what is being counted (words, letters, phonemes, syllables. morae).

Comment: @jlawler Yes, as far as I'm aware most researcher measure tempo in sybllables per second or words per minute. But other units would be fine, too. Do you know any papers or studies?